# Sum two sequences in R to yield a third sequence

Tags: r, sequence, addition

I have a sequence of numbers in R

```
A <- c(1,4,2,5,3,6)
```

I have a second sequence as follows

```
B <- c(0,6,12)
```

I would like to sum the elements of the two sequences such that I get the following:

```
final_output = c(1,4,2,5,3,6, 7,10,8,11,9,12,13,16,14,17,15,18)
```

I have tried `A + B` but am getting:

```
  1 10 14  5  9 18
```

I am unable to get the answer. Could someone guide me?

Comment: neat. Thank you.

Comment: can you post it as an answer. so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a list of sequences and then `unlist()` with merge all of the sequences together.

Does this work:

```
B<- c(0, 6,12)
A<-c(1,4,2,5,3,6)

unlist(lapply(B, function(x){x+A}))
[1]  1  4  2  5  3  6  7 10  8 11  9 12 13 16 14 17 15 18
```

Comment: yes. I figured the unlist but that was quite elegant

Answer (score 1):

```
vec <- c()

for(i in 1:length(B)){
vec <- c(vec, A + B[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer` -

```
c(outer(A, B, `+`))
#[1]  1  4  2  5  3  6  7 10  8 11  9 12 13 16 14 17 15 18
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `rowSums` and `expand.grid`:

```
rowSums(expand.grid(A, B))
```

which gives:

> ```
>  [1]  1  4  2  5  3  6  7 10  8 11  9 12 13 16 14 17 15 18
> ```